# Взять строки из текста Python

Tags: python, текст

у меня есть текст

> BTC
> $58,764.60
> -5.54 %
> 35%
> ETH
> $3,974.78
> -7.01 %
> 46%
> BNB
> $452.37
> -7.16 %
> 34%.. и так далее

Как взять часть текста отсюда для бота? Например

> BTC $58,764.60 -5.54 %
> 35% это например тоже не нужно)

Comment: Отформатируйте текст так, что бы было понятно, что вам нужно, а что нет и как в реальности выглядит текст. Сейчас непонятно ничего толком.

Comment: непонятно какую именно часть нужно взять и чем эта часть отличается от других

Answer (score 2):

т.е. надо разбить строку на блоки типа `[ВАЛЮТА] [СТОИМОСТЬ] [РОСТ] [КАКОЙ_ТО ПРОЦЕНТ]`?

в вашем примере проблема с пробелом перед `%`, так что я сделал бы такой алгоритм:

1. заменить  `%` на `%` (удалить ненужный пробел)
2. разбить строку на слова через `.split()`
3. полученный массив разбирать на четверки значений
4. из четверок значений собрать новые строки (или что вам надо)

Comment: BTC $58764.60 -5.54% 35% - получилось сделать вот такую строку, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('abc.txt') as file_in:
    text = file_in.read()
text = text.replace(" %", "%")
spisok_last = []
x = 0

str_list1 = text.split('\n',640)
str_list = (str_list1[0],str_list1[1],str_list1[2],str_list1[3])
while x < 160:
    str_list = (str_list1[0],str_list1[1],str_list1[2],str_list1[3])
    #print(str_list)
    spisok_last.append(str_list)
    spisok_last.append('\n')
    convertList = ''.join(map(str,spisok_last))
    del str_list1[:4]
    x = x+1
convertList = convertList.replace("'", "")
convertList = convertList.replace("(", "")
convertList = convertList.replace(")", "")
convertList = convertList.replace(",", "")
print(convertList)
```

Что-то такое смог родить)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]